# Application Crashed while async task is override

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on windows phone 8.1.here I am create simple two page first page contain two button.

```
   <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnNextPage" Content="Next Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnNextPage_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btnMessageDisplay" Content="Message Display" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnMessageDisplay_Click" />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here First button simple done nvaigation from one page to another and second is display simple message dialog box like as following.

```
  MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("","");
    async private void btnMessageDisplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        msg.Content = "Hello Friends...";
        msg.Title = "Message";
       await msg.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void btnNextPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));

    }
```

this is work fine. but problem is occur while hold first button and twice click on btnMessageDisplay button Application getting crashed.

i know why it's happens because of async task.but i don't know solution of this problem.
Please give me the solution.

I am getting following Exception.

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in AsyncTesting.exe but was not handled in user code

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: Please give us more details about the crash. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: So you're doing something for which you have no access, that's pretty much all that anyone here can say. On which line do you get that exception? What is the stack trace?

Comment: on this line await msg.ShowAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exacly find the guideline at MSDN, but the system on WP can show one dialog at a time. When you try to show the second dialog, the system will throw *UnauthorizedException*.

Do a simple test:

```cs
private void TestBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) };
    DispatcherTimer timer2 = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4) };
    timer1.Tick += async (s1, e1) => { timer1.Stop(); await new MessageDialog("First").ShowAsync(); };
    timer2.Tick += async (s2, e2) => { timer2.Stop(); await new MessageDialog("Second").ShowAsync(); };
    timer1.Start(); timer2.Start();
}
```

If you close the first dialog quicky, it will be ok, but if you don't, after a second (when the second dialog is to be shown), you will have an exception.

The same situation is in your case - you rapidly click the button responsible for showing the dialog - the first one shows up, but the second resolved clicked event throws exception. In this case, you ca use for example simple flag:

```cs
private bool btnResolved = true;
async private void btnMessageDisplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!btnResolved) return;
    btnResolved = false;
    msg.Content = "Hello Friends...";
    msg.Title = "Message";
    await msg.ShowAsync();
    btnResolved = true;
}
```

You can also think of *Disabling* button instead of using a flag.

Comment: Thanx Bro,It's Working..but i think it's one kind of patching.

Comment: @ChiragSolanki It's just a matter of design. There are many places where there can be exception thrown and you have to handle them.